# Find the closed form of the following sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I would like to find the closed form of the sum:

$f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(z+k)^2}$

The question firstly ask me to prove that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{Z}$ and has period $2$. I proved and this may be helpful.

I tried to differentiate and integrate each term but I cannot built an equality between the new sum and $f$.

I found the solution but I cannot understant. It says $f=-g'$ where $g$ has single poles with residue $(-1)^k$. Then $g=\pi/sin(\pi x)$, but I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(z+k)^2}$$
Consider the function $g(z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}\frac{1}{(z+x)^2}$ and integral in the complex plane along a big circle of radius $R$ in the clockwise direction. It can be shown that this integral $\to0$ as $R\to\infty$ (because $|g(x)|\to0$ as $\sim\frac{1}{R^2}$). We have simple poles at $x=\pi k$ ($k$ - integres) and one second order pole at $x=-z$.

Therefore,
$$0=\oint_{C_R}=2\pi i \sum Res\,\, g(x)=2\pi i \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty Res \frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}\frac{1}{(z+x)^2}|_{z=k}+2\pi i Res\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}\frac{1}{(z+x)^2}|_{x=-z}\Rightarrow$$
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty Res \frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}\frac{1}{(z+x)^2}|_{z=k}=S(z)=-Res\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}\frac{1}{(z+x)^2}|_{x=-z}=-\frac{d}{dx}
\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}\Bigr)|_{x=-z}$$
$$S(z)=\pi^2\frac{\cos\pi z}{\sin^2\pi z}$$